# How to remove a javascript function from a parent theme main.js file with a child theme js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, overriding

I have a function of a main theme, which takes up to 71% of the costs (devtools profiler), because the function is executed with every scroll event and without delay or debouncing. Nevertheless the function seems to be useless in the behaviour I am using the theme, so I'd like to remove it by overriding it, but can't get it done.

The function in the main.js file looks like:

```
function fusionSideHeaderScroll() {
var $mediaQueryIpad = Modernizr.mq( 'only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (orientation: portrait)' ) ||  Modernizr.mq( 'only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)' ),
    $documentHeight,
    $windowPosition,
    $windowHeight,
    $bodyHeight,
    $adminbarHeight,
    $sideHeader,
    $sideHeaderWrapper,
    $sideHeaderHeight,
    $boxedWrapperOffset,
    $topOffset;

if ( ! $mediaQueryIpad ) {
    $documentHeight     = jQuery( document ).height();
    $windowPosition     = jQuery( window ).scrollTop();
    $windowHeight       = jQuery( window ).height();
    $bodyHeight         = jQuery( 'body' ).height();
    $adminbarHeight     = jQuery( '#wpadminbar' ).height();
    $sideHeader         = jQuery( '#side-header' );
    $sideHeaderWrapper  = jQuery( '.side-header-wrapper' );
    $sideHeaderHeight   = $sideHeaderWrapper.outerHeight();
    $boxedWrapperOffset = 0;

    if ( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'layout-boxed-mode' ) && jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'side-header-right' ) ) {
        $sideHeader = jQuery( '.side-header-wrapper' );
        $boxedWrapperOffset = jQuery( '#boxed-wrapper' ).offset().top;
    }

    if ( Modernizr.mq( 'only screen and (max-width:' + avadaVars.side_header_break_point + 'px)' ) ) {

        if ( ! $sideHeader.hasClass( 'fusion-is-sticky' ) ) {
            $sideHeader.css({
                'bottom': '',
                'position': ''
            });
        }

        return;
    }

    if ( $sideHeaderHeight + $adminbarHeight > $windowHeight ) {
        $sideHeader.css( 'height', 'auto' );
        if ( $windowPosition > window.lastWindowPosition ) {
            if ( window.avadaTop ) {
                window.avadaTop = false;
                $topOffset = ( $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top > 0 ) ? $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top - $boxedWrapperOffset : $adminbarHeight;
                $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'top: ' + $topOffset + 'px; height: auto;' );
            } else if ( ! window.avadaBottom && $windowPosition + $windowHeight > $sideHeaderHeight + $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top && $sideHeaderHeight + $adminbarHeight < $bodyHeight ) {
                window.avadaBottom = true;
                $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'position: fixed; bottom: 0; top: auto; height: auto;' );
            }
        } else if ( $windowPosition < window.lastWindowPosition ) {
            if ( window.avadaBottom ) {
                window.avadaBottom = false;
                $topOffset = ( $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top > 0 ) ? $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top - $boxedWrapperOffset : $adminbarHeight;
                $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'top: ' + $topOffset + 'px; height: auto;' );
            } else if ( ! window.avadaTop && $windowPosition + $adminbarHeight < $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top ) {
                window.avadaTop = true;
                $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'position: fixed; height: auto;' );
            }
        } else {
            window.avadaTop = window.avadaBottom = false;

            $topOffset = ( $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top > 0 ) ? $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top - $boxedWrapperOffset : $adminbarHeight;

            if ( $windowHeight > window.lastWindowHeight && $bodyHeight > $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top  + $boxedWrapperOffset + $sideHeaderHeight && $windowPosition + $windowHeight > $sideHeaderWrapper.offset().top + $sideHeaderHeight ) {
                $topOffset += $windowHeight - window.lastWindowHeight;
            }
            $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'top:' + $topOffset + 'px; height: auto;' );
        }
    } else {
        window.avadaTop = true;
        $sideHeader.attr( 'style', 'position: fixed;' );
    }

    window.lastWindowPosition = $windowPosition;
    window.lastWindowHeight   = $windowHeight;
}
}
```

After the function is defined it is binded to a scroll event with

```
// Make the side header scrolling happen
jQuery( window ).on( 'scroll', fusionSideHeaderScroll );
jQuery( window ).on( 'resize', fusionSideHeaderScroll );
```

I've already tried to write in my child theme's js file

```
 function fusionSideHeaderScroll() {
     //do nothing
 }
```

In this case the function still remains to be executed, which seems to be logicial since it is attached to every scroll event. Is there a way to detach the function from the scroll event with javascript?

Comment: paste the code inside the original function `fusionSideHeaderScroll()` there should be something in there you could use to unbind the event

Comment: You should be able to unbind the scroll event as Sergio said. The reason you can't just replace the function is probably due to a scope issue. See this example. https://jsfiddle.net/3e03p5z6/1/

Comment: @SergioAlen, I've edited my post for you. Mayby you can find sth. to unbind the function!

Answer (score 0):

Try unbinding the scroll and resize events using `.off()`, like this:

```
jQuery( window ).off( 'scroll', fusionSideHeaderScroll );
jQuery( window ).off( 'resize', fusionSideHeaderScroll );
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise sergio, sadly it seems that it did not solve my issue, I get an error message saying that fusionSideHeaderScroll is not defined, when I'm trying to place this code into the child themes js file.

Comment: okay, so I have just tried to paste your advise into the main.js file, just to see what is happening. Then the desired effect takes place and the scroll event is detached. So the question is how I can achieve this from another external file and why it does not work up to now. Is this, because the function is not a global function?

Comment: Is your site live? can you share a link so we can have a look? it's most likely a scope issue.

Comment: Hey, yes it is already live, but I don't let it crawl by google bots and would prefer to keep it private since I am done with the work, which still may last few months. Is there a way to send you the link on a privat channel, for the case you want to have a look? If this is too much effort for your time, no worries mate, in this case I'll come back here when the site is live and repost the question :-)